# How do I create a Powershell alias (or function, or cmdlet) that runs in the same process as my shell?

Tags: windows, powershell, process

In Unix, I create a lot of aliases/functions. Here is my workflow:

```
* I have a file named 'aliases.txt' in my $HOME directory
* I have a quick command to edit that file
* I have an alias named 'sa' that sources that alias file. I.e.

  alias sa='. $HOME/aliases.txt
```

So I can quickly and easily create, modify, and use new aliases.

I'm trying to re-create the same work flow in Powershell and it doesn't work. I've got the aliases.ps1 file in my $HOME directory. I tried creating an 'sa' alias, but of course a Powershell alias can't contain an argument. So I've tried

```
function sa {. $HOME\aliases.ps1 }
```

I can run it but changes in my aliases.pl1 file don't get reflected in my shell session. I'm assuming it's because Windows runs the 'sa' function in a new process, while Unix runs functions and aliases in the same process. How can I get my 'sa' back?

(BTW, "Type '. $HOME\aliases.ps1' at the command line each time" is not the answer I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be a bit pedantic, the command is not being run in a different process, it is being run in a different scope.

Comment: Ah! And so I learn about 'scope' today. Thanks. (Pedantic is good, when computers are involved.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would

```
. sa
```

be terse enough?  You just need to dot-source the function call into the current scope.  (Note there needs to be a space between the dot and the function name).

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know you use "." in front of a function to keep it in-process. I tried it and it worked the way you described. I'll gladly accept ". sa" as terse enough.

Comment: You can also explicitly scope the new aliases using the -scope parameter of set-alias, to force the aliases to be created a parent scope.

Comment: The problem isn't separate processes.  Everything in PowerShell is in the same process unless you launch an external application.  The problem is scope.  When you "dot-sourced" the script in the function, it ran with the function's scope.  So any functions or aliases defined would go away after the function finished.  I would suggest defining those aliases with global scope, since that is what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What are you trying to do? Some parts of your question doesn't make sense.</strike>

Ok, I understand better now.

`Import-Alias` is exactly for this purpose! Edit the file and do `Import-Alias file` and you get the new aliases that you have added.

---

Your flow:

Use the Set-Alias command to setup an alias and add that to your profile or just add that function to profile.

```
notepad $profile
(add the next in notepad)
function sa {. HOME\aliases.ps1 }
```

Now sa, should be available and the aliases.ps1 can be setup to use `Set-Alias` and add the aliases.

You are trying to map what you do in unix EXACTLY to Powershell. You should try and use what powershell has to offer:

Powershell flow:

```
 notepad $profile
 (in notepad)
 Set-Alias <alias> <command>
```

Just add Set-Alias command to your profile.

Or use `Export-Alias` to export into a file and add `Import-Alias` to import from the file in your profile.

All these are excellently explained here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692685.aspx

Comment: Import-alias won't replace existing aliases (and I'm guessing functions), and I use this specifically to write part of an function, test run it, update the function, and replace it with the new definition

Comment: Also, you are recommending I type "Import-aliases $HOME\aliases.ps1" each time. When I put it in a function, like you suggest, it doesn't work. If I type 'sa', Powershell runs it in another process, that process gets the new alias, and then goes away. The alias doesn't get changed in the original process.

Comment: @Jonathan - Agreed, it is as you say. Learn't something today :)